# pySerial could not open port COM6: Element not found

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

i tried to use the following code:

```
    import serial
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 56700
    ser.port = 'COM6'
    ser.open() # HERE IS THE ERROR
```

When i do it from Python shell, typing line by line, it works and i can recieve data from a bluetooth device. But when i run it from cmd (C:\>python serial.py) it raises the error "could not open port COM6: Element not found". I can see in the bluetooth device that it connects for a second and then disconnects.
Anyone know what this is?
BTW, Im using Windows 7 64-Bits and Python 2.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to run the Command prompt as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by adding `time.sleep(5)` around `ser.open()`. So it would look like this:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 56700
ser.port = 'COM6'
time.sleep(5)
ser.open()
time.sleep(5)
```

I didn't experiment much with the code, but you probably don't have to sleep for 5 seconds, you can probably just sleep for 0.1 seconds and it would still work. This is probably not the best way to fix it, but it works.